# Storing Express sessions on Memcached

Tags: node.js, express, memcached, connection-pooling, express-session

I am working on an node+express application and using [connect-memcached](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached) for storing express sessions which uses [Memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/memcached) client for communicating with the Memcached server. I want to use Memcached via a pool of connections. So far I have tried this:-

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MemcachedStore = require('connect-memcached')(session);
var servers = [];
if (typeof cacheAddr === 'string') servers.push(cacheAddr + ':' + cachePort);
else {
  for(var i = 0; i < cacheAddr.length; i++)
    servers.push(cacheAddr[i] + ':' + cachePort);
  }
  var store = {
    secret  : secret,
    key     : 'its',
    proxy   : 'true',
    store   : new MemcachedStore({
      hosts: servers,
      prefix: 'sess:',
      poolSize: 200
    }),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    unset: 'destroy'
  };
}
var sessionStore = session(store);
```

netstat on my memcached server shows 2 connections from my application server.
Any idea, how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. The load was not enough, so I was not seeing 200 active connections. On increasing the load, I got to see 200 active connections.